# Textbook recommendations: Weakly almost periodic functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ergodic-theory, textbook-recommendation

I am currently studying Ergodic Theory from Glasner’s book - in it, weakly almost periodic functions play a large role, as well as general “means” and unitary representations of groups on Hilbert spaces.

I cannot seem to grasp the motivation or intuition behind these notions. What text would be best for me to get a better feel for these objects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what good the inuition is meant to be without grappling with examples. Is the motivation what you are primarily looking for?

Comment: FWIW, I belong to the school of thought that intuition is something that comes after examples and just before or just after formalism is introduced, but I appreciate that this doesn't work for everyone

Comment: Possibly Uri Bader's answer to this MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232610/what-does-the-unique-mean-on-weakly-almost-periodic-functions-look-like holds some pointers towards the kind of thing you are after

Comment: "Abstract ergodic theorems and weak almost periodic functions" by Eberlein is an excelent resource IMO.

Answer (score 1):

To me the best intuition for almost periodicity is Weil’s ([1940](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=5741), Chap. VII), nicely exposed in Dixmier ([1982](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=458185), Chap. 16): Any topological group $\mathrm G$ maps to a “universal” (“Bohr”) compact group $b\mathrm G$, through which all morphisms $\varphi$ of $\mathrm G$ to compact groups (or all finite-dimensional representations of $\mathrm G$) factor uniquely:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image: bG]
Now almost periodic functions on $\mathrm G$ are just those $f$ that factor through a continuous $\tilde f$ on $b\mathrm G$, and $f$’s mean is just $\tilde f$’s Haar integral. (When $\mathrm G$ is locally compact abelian, $b\mathrm G$ is the Pontryagin dual of $\mathrm G$’s dual-*made-discrete*.)

Weak almost periodicity is a variant for which Glasner ([p. 47](//books.google.com/books?id=FBL-CAAAQBAJ&ots=YFTNYG6iz3&pg=PA47&dq=%22Weak+almost+periodicity%22)) gives some references; one could add the “very substantial survey” of Štern ([2005](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2167813)), which mentions applications to ergodic theory.

Comment: A word of warning (for others reading): the WAP compactification of a group is usually no longer a group, but a semi-topological semigroup (multiplication is separately continuous). So some of the intuition from the AP (=Bohr) coimpactification is potentially misleading

Comment: @Yemon Good point! If I understand Glasner (p. 43) correctly, bG $=$ Gelfand space of AP(G) injects into Z $:=$ Gelfand space of WAP(G); the latter’s $mean$ is integration against the injected Haar measure; and we have WAP(G) $=$ AP(G) $\oplus\ker(mean(|\cdot|))$.